# Anonymous pull on docker repo in artifactory

Tags: authentication, docker, artifactory

I am on artifactory version 4.6 and have the following requirement on the docker registry.

Allow anonymous pulls on docker repository
Force authentication on the SAME docker repository

I know this is avaliable out of the box on the later versions of artifactory. However upgrading isnt an option for us for a while.

Does the following work around work?

1. Create a virtual docker repository on port 8443 and don't force authentication , call it docker-virtual
2. Create a local docker repository and force authentication, call it docker-local on port 8444
3. Configure 'docker-virtual' with the default deployment directory as 'docker-local'

   `docker pull docker-virtual should work
   docker push docker-virtual should ask for credentials`

Upon failure , I should be able to docker `login docker-virtual`
and `docker push docker-virtual/myImage`

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about the artifactory side, but perhaps the following Docker advice helps.

You can start run two registries, one RW with authentication, and a second RO without any authentication, in Docker:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry \
  -v `pwd`/certs:/certs:ro \
  -v `pwd`/auth/htpasswd:/auth/htpasswd:ro \
  -v `pwd`/registry:/var/lib/registry \
  -e "REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/host-cert.pem" \
  -e "REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/host-key.pem" \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=My Registry" \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd" \
  -e "REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY=/var/lib/registry" \
  registry:2

docker run -d -p 5001:5000 --restart=always --name registry-ro \
  -v `pwd`/certs:/certs:ro \
  -v `pwd`/auth/htpasswd:/auth/htpasswd:ro \
  -v `pwd`/registry:/var/lib/registry:ro \
  -e "REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/host-cert.pem" \
  -e "REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/host-key.pem" \
  -e "REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY=/var/lib/registry" \
  registry:2
```

Note the volume settings for /var/lib/registry in each container. Then to pull from the anonymous registry, you'd just need to change the port. Since the filesystem is RO, any attempt to push to 5001 will fail.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing you can achieve is failing on docker push without credentials (while succeeding with pull).

Comment: what happens if a virtual docker repository is configured with a default deployment directory that forces authentication?

Comment: If the user is not logged in, the push will fail. Docker does not support any interactive login. You either login in front, with `docker login` command, or not.

Comment: Is there a way to reroute the port , somehow login as 'doker login virtual-docker-repo' but this routes it to the actual local docker deployment repo only for pushes?

Comment: I am not sure what you trying to achieve or what's the problem? If everybody has a username:password everybody can login to the virtual repo. Then you set the permissions to fail on deployment for certain users/groups and to succeed to others. Won't that work?

Comment: I've updated the question. My problem is when I fail for the docker push I should be able to login using the virtual endpoint only. I want to hide the local docker repository from the user and need only one endpoint exposed.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this works with artifactory sorry.... you could try this handy project for docker registry auth.

Configure the registry to use this https://hub.docker.com/r/cesanta/docker_auth/

```
# registry config.yml
...
auth:
  token:
    # can be the same as your docker registry if you use nginx to proxy /auth to docker_auth
    # https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/nginx/
     realm: "example.com:5001/auth" 
     service: "Docker registry"
     issuer: "Docker Registry auth server"
     rootcertbundle: /certs/domain.crt
```

And allow anonymous with the corresponding ACL

```
# cesanta/docker_auth auth_config.yml
...

users:
  # Password is specified as a BCrypt hash. Use htpasswd -B to generate.
  "admin":
    password: "$2y$05$LO.vzwpWC5LZGqThvEfznu8qhb5SGqvBSWY1J3yZ4AxtMRZ3kN5jC"  # badmin
  "": {}  # Allow anonymous (no "docker login") access.


ldap_auth:
  # See: https://github.com/cesanta/docker_auth/blob/master/examples/ldap_auth.yml

acl:
  # See https://github.com/cesanta/docker_auth/blob/master/examples/reference.yml#L178
  - match: {account: "/.+/"}
    actions: ["*"]
    comment: "Logged in users do anything."
  - match: {account: ""}
    actions: ["pull"]
    comment: "Anonymous users can pull anything."
  # Access is denied by default.
```

Comment: I didn't use this but it looks similar to what i have: https://the.binbashtheory.com/creating-private-docker-registry-2-0-with-token-authentication-service/